# Using Dragon (MacSpeech) Dictate with XCode?

Tags: xcode, macos, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am sure there are a lot of people who code and who, for one reason or another, are temporarily or permanently unable to use a keyboard to do so.

I am trying to find out if it is worthwhile to get Dragon Dictate (or any other speech recognition software) to be able to keep on coding while my arm is in a cast.

Do any of you have any experience with this? (How well)does it work?

Answer (score 3):

I invite you to try CMUSphinx project.

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net

You'll probably find it non-working initially and will have to read a lot. But I hope invested effort will help you and other developers with casted arms ;)

Comment: Just to confirm,  after you have tried using sphinx,  you will also need a cast for your brain :p

Answer (score 0):

I have been plagued with RSI for 10 years.  I doubt there is a solution that I haven't tried.

I got as far as creating a blueprint for a working solution,  which goes as follows:

you create a grid. going horizontally you have the consonant phonemes.   going down you have the vowel phonemes. English uses probably close to 20 consonant sounds and 13 vowel sounds,  though some of these are dipthong/tripthong.

so, after weeding out ones which are too close to their neighbour, you are left with at least 100 distinct phoneme pairs.

you then adapt Sphinx using ONLY these 10+10 phonemes,  and 100 word dictionary

and map a different keyboard character to each slot.

this will leave a lot of slots left over which you can customise.

then you speak to your computer using a sequence of nonsense 'la-lu-be-ni-pa-ta-bu-rru...'  and it types as you go

you could conceivably rack up a huge speed dictating this way, very possibly faster than a trained typist, bearing in mind you use all those crazy symbols when you code.

That's a big project. Maybe one day I will have a crack at it if no one else does.

I christened the project 'spascii' (ala 'speak ASCII') but I never started coding it.

second thing to bear in mind is that programmers use the mouse a lot.  I used to use a head pointer device called trackIR ( it used infrared ) and that was really decent. I later improved by pulling apart a gyroscopic mouse sticking the gyroscopes on a cap.   This gave really decent performance. I was clicking using a guitar footpedal wired into the mouse buttons, but in theory you could just assign one phoneme pair for left click,  left down,  left up, etc

Answer (score 0):

http://voicecode.io

I recently released VoiceCode, a coding-by-voice solution I created to solve my own RSI issues.

I use it for coding in Sublime Text and Xcode, as well as general computer usage. The great thing about this solution is that all the commands can be chained into "command phrases" so you don't have to pause between every individual command like you do with other voice command solutions.

It has builtin support for all standard variable-name formats (snake case, camel case, etc), has builtin commands for every permutation of keyboard shortcuts (ie command-shift-5, command-option-shift-T, and so on), has cursor movement commands, app switching commands, window switching commands, commands for symbol combos like "=>", "||", ">=", etc, and tons more. Plus it is very easy to add your own custom commands as well.